# Is there any way to make a ordinary class transaction aware in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jta

Hi folks
Suppose I have a hypothetical class that has nothing to do with neither a database nor a message queue. Is there any way to make the methods of this class **transaction aware**? 
To explain my point, suppose I have a class that can be used to write given info on a file. For example something like below

```
public class WriterToFileSystem
{
   private fileName="current_file_name";
   
   public void addToFile(String textToAppendToFile)
   {
      //---add $textToAppendToFile to already opened file byte by byte
   }   
}
```

and there is another class that uses objects of this class like so:

```
public class Appender
{
   private WriterToFileSystem writer;

   @Transactionl // making it transactional so that when exception happens all changes get discarded
   public void append(String someLongText)
   {
      writer.addToFile()
   }
}
```

Suppose that file system has file size limit 200 Bytes and currently we have written 100 Bytes to it. calling `addToFile` method will be causeing an exception to be raised for the last byte of given string with size of 101 bytes.
 Is there any way to make first class transaction aware (perhaps by implementing a certain interface) so that by decorating second class's method with @Transactional annotation ,transaction manager can role back all the data that has been added to the file after last call.

Please keep in mind that this is a hypothetical scenario, I'm aware that there are some tools that can provide similar functionalities for files. Its a general question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Transactions ? it used to be known as JTA java transation api.